# A couple of questions about transformers

Tags: transformer, ac, dc

1: I accidentally supplied 9v to a 4.5v - 0 - 4.5v transformer like this: [image: image of circuit]

And it was working for a about a second and then it stopped and isnt working. Have i killed it?

2: Can you use a [square wave DC signal](https://cdn.eeweb.com/comments/ac-vs-dc-square-wave1541638060.png) to create a AC square wave output or do you need other stuff.

Comment: What does it mean that it stopped working? What did you do? What result did you expect? What actually happened?

Comment: @ThePhoton it just started producing _really weak_ output and then I connected it to 4.5v and it wanst prodcuing any.

Comment: Did you supply 9 VAC or 9 VDC to it?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine DC square wave

Comment: But like jp314 says, a so-called "DC square wave" is simply an AC square wave... but with a DC offset.  So you are sending 4.5V DC and 4.5V AC (both) through the transformer. How will the transformer handle 4.5VDC on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't supply a signal with a DC component to a transformer. So you can't (shouldn't) apply a 'square wave DC signal' (there's no such thing).

If you apply an AC-coupled square wave, you'll get a square wave out. If the source has a DC offset, connect it to the transformer via a capacitor (might need 100's of uF).

Comment: This is what i mean by dc square wave: [link](https://cdn.eeweb.com/comments/ac-vs-dc-square-wave1541638060.png)

Comment: Add an electrolytic capacitor in series. Use a value where 1/(6*frequency*C) is << VOUT/LOADCURRENT

Comment: That capacitor and transformer is going to round out your square wave, though.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: I accidentally supplied 9v to a 4.5v - 0 - 4.5v transformer like this

Most likely you have burnt it, because you supplied twice the voltage the transformer was designed for. Depending on the transformer, they can accept higher input voltages, say, for example, up to 130% of rated voltage, without damage. But, over a certain knee, the transformer starts to consume energy by itself instead of transferring it; this can damage the coil.